# File.Delete also deleted the wrong file

Tags: c#

I have a `Listbox` which work with specific extension files. If i choose another format, my application automatically converts the files to the correct format in the same folder (another extension) and add all the files with the wrong extension to a `List` (`listToRemove`) and remove them from my `Listbox` after i clean my `List` but first i want to delete all this files from my computer and my problem is that my appliction deleted also the file with the correct extension

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBoxFiles.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string path = (string)listBoxFiles.Items[i];
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

    if (fileInfo.Extension != ".avi")
    {
        listToRemove.Add(path);
    }
}

if (listToRemove.Count != 0)
{
    //method who convert the files to the new format and add the new files into my Listbox
    (new System.Threading.Thread(sendFilesToConvertToAvi)).Start(); 
}

foreach (string file in listToRemove) 
{
    File.Delete(file);
    listBoxFiles.Items.Remove(file);                  
}

public void sendFilesToConvertToAvi()
{
    if (listToRemove.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (String file in listToRemove)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

        myClassWhoConvertTheFiles = new myClassWhoConvertTheFiles (fileInfo);

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            listBoxFiles.Items.Add(myClassWhoConvertTheFiles ._newFileName);
        });

        count++;
    }

    listToRemove.RemoveRange(0, listToRemove.Count);
}
```

Comment: Try removing it from the list before the `Delete` operation.

Comment: Did the files with the correct extensions some how make it into your `listToRemove`? What do you see when you debug?

Comment: Your file is in the remove list, can you post more of your code?

Comment: Could you please post the bit of code adding the files to remove to `listToRemove`?

Comment: first i try to clean my list and the result was the same, and i saw in my list (listToRemove) that the list contain only the extension that i want to delete

Comment: You should delete the files in the new thread.

Comment: how can i delete all those files with new thread and wait until its finish and only than continue ? (i am using .Net 3.5)

Comment: Can you show us this method: sendFilesToConvertToAvi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely in:

```
sendFilesToConvertToAvi
```

The code for which you don't show. This:

```
    File.Delete(file);
    listBoxFiles.Items.Remove(file);
```

looks like it should be in a callback from sendFilesToConvertToAvi. i.e. post convert.

Comment: sendFilesToConvertToAvi function added

Comment: OK i put the File.delete in sendFilesToConvertToAvi  and now its OK, can you explain me what the different ?

Comment: Your initial code was subject to a something of a "race condition" whereby the time it took to convert the file was greater than time it took to advance to the next line of the list. So it wasn't that your converted file was being deleted but rather that the item in the list was being deleted BEFORE it had a chance to be read and thus converted. No conversion took place in you original code. Now you are deleting the file AFTER it has been converted. I would go for a callback routine/event tho as your converter code shouldn't care about the delete afterward == better reuse of code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is related to way you use threading: you are removing not yet converted files.

`File.Delete(file);` has to be executed in thread where you did convertion (i.e. `sendFilesToConvertToAvi`)

Here is what you generally would do, assuming that this is UI application:

1. On button press start another thread using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).
2. In same code section, update your ListBox by removing files being converted. You might want to disable ListBox here.
3. Add progress bar to your application so you see how conversion is going.
4. On callback, after job is done, delete not needed files. You might want to enable ListBox again.

Hope this helps.

Here is some code I quickly wrote. It works good. (You might want to add progress bar :) ).

```
    private List<string> listToRemove = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBoxFiles.Items.Add("1.avi");
        listBoxFiles.Items.Add("2.avi");
        listBoxFiles.Items.Add("3.wrong");
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var file in listToRemove)
        {
            // Imitate hard conversion
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            var newFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(file, "avi");
            // save NEW file to file system here...

            // delete old file from file system
            File.Delete(file);
        }
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var file in listToRemove)
        {
            var newFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(file, "avi");
            listBoxFiles.Items.Add(newFileName);
        }
        listBoxFiles.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listToRemove = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listBoxFiles.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string path = (string)listBoxFiles.Items[i];
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

            if (fileInfo.Extension != ".avi")
            {
                listToRemove.Add(path);
                listBoxFiles.Items.Remove(path);
            }
        }

        listBoxFiles.Enabled = false;
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(listToRemove);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why using BackgroundWorker ? i already using another thread to convert my files: (new System.Threading.Thread(sendFilesToConvertToAvi)).Start();

Comment: In that case you will have more control over what is going on with your conversion.